# AOP Spring @AfterReturning not calling the aspects method properly

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I have an annotation.

```java
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{

}
```

My Aspect class is like that

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyCustomAsspect{

    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut="@annotation(MyCustomAnnotation)",
            returning="retVal")
    public void publishMessage(JoinPoint jp, Object retVal) throws Throwable {


    }
}
```

My Service class is

```java
@Service
public class ServiceClass{

@MyCustomAnnotation
public Object someMethod(){
return new Object();
}

}
```

Above are mentioned classes i am not sure why my aspect not working. I am new to Spring AOP . Please help me  it shall  be very thankful.

Comment: What exactly is your pointcut?

Comment: You are missing or improper point cut

Comment: @annotation(MyCustomAnnotation) this is my pointcut

Comment: Try adding 
`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` above your MyCustomAsspect class

Comment: @BishalJaiswal it is already present on  my SpringBootApplication class

Comment: @BishalJaiswal Not working bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to pointcut declaration. As spring documentation says

> @annotation - limits matching to join points where the subject of the
>   join point (method being executed in Spring AOP) has the given
>   annotation

So I order to make this work

```
@Aspect
public class MyCustomAsspect{

    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut="execution(public * *(..)) and @annotation(MyCustomAnnotation)",
            returning="retVal")
    public void publishMessage(JoinPoint jp, Object retVal) throws Throwable {


    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why the OP accepted this answer because IMO it does not solve the problem. The additional `execution(public * *(..)) and ` does not change the aspect's behaviour in any way. So whatever solved the OP's problem, it must have been something else. I am just commenting on this so that nobody believes it is a real solution. For example, it is much more likely that something like a fully-qualified class name such as `@annotation(my.package.MyCustomAnnotation)` actually solved it.